# Restrict user to view source of HTML

Tags: html, security

Is there any way, by which I can restrict user to view page source for HTML page or alternate way to encrypt all data of HTML page specially for HTML forms ?

Comment: HTML data is not intended to be secret, but you can hide a lot of business logic using server side scripting. As your question stands now, you are asking on "I have this document freely available for anyone to see, how do I prevent people from seeing it", the answer is 1) don't publish your website or 2) rethink your intent. Also, what on earth do you have in your HTML that you don't want your user to see, your passwords? Your deepest darkest secrets?

Comment: is this because you have sensitive data in hidden input fields or something?

Comment: If you don't want the user to see something, then don't send it to him.

Comment: @Dmitry lol. darketst secretes  !!

Comment: @Dmitry I am agree with you.

Comment: @KameshJungi if you agree with then vote for close the question, which serves nothing for community

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way. You can ask to JavaScript to protect right-click but with F12 (in most browsers I mean) you can access to it. There is no way, and honestly, you have no reason to protect your HTML because you have nothing critical in your HTML.

Maybe in your JavaScript. Here you can do something. Excuse me, I would like you HAVE to do something. Minify and uglify your scripts (uglifyjs, yahoo compiler, google closure compiler, etc...)

Comment: If you have your deepest darkest secrets in your javascripts, you might want to resort to using server side scripting. Uglifying scripts is silly, maybe compressing the source so it requires your server to send less data to the user.

Comment: Yes I agree but if you have some logic you want to protect in front script, the only way to protect it (and it doesn't really protect it) is to minify it. But it's not the best way to protect something.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable right-click/context menu but user can still access source code via menu. There is no way to hide HTML as far as I know.

Comment: Not efficient because you can inspect. By right-click or in the main menu of each browser. And even if you can block this too (say me how), you can use the F12 on your keyboard or "more-"complex,the Ctrl=U shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You can use several things to try (utilizing javascript for instance) or try to obfuscate the source, but the bottom line is that you won't be able to protect your html, because it will be at the end delivered in 'plaintext' to the client's browser in order to show him the actual page. And most of the so called 'protective' measures can be bypassed by inbuilt tools of any modern browser... So in essence, no you can't.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. You're already sending the HTML, as well as JavaScript, to the user's browser.

If they want, they'll be able to see it, if it's by means of a functionality of their browser or another mechanism isn't something you can do anything about.

As pointed out in the comments, If you don't want the user to see something, then don't send it to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you encrypt the source then the user and the browser will not be able to read the content anymore meaing it wont be viewable by anyone. If you did use a script to encrypt it then search engines would not be able to index your pages at all

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide the HTML but actually if you really care that much you encrypt the content with Javascript.

Obviously if Javascript can decrypt it then so can anybody with enough time, but it will deter the average layman.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blencrypt.htm